# Solr delete operation using Camel

Tags: solr, apache-camel

I have a use case where I want to delete the solr documents (by id) using Camel.

I searched the documentation but I m not getting any handle on examples on delete operation.

If I have to use DELETE_BY_ID, I m not clear on where do set the value of the document id.. is it in the message body or header? Appreciate a small example.

Also, is there a way to do batch delete. Because I have multiple documents to delete from solr.

Thanks.

Comment: just updated the docs with a delete example...see http://camel.apache.org/solr.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the batch delete, you can use DELETE_BY_QUERY or use a List/splitter to call the DELETE_BY_ID multiple times and then commit at the end, etc...something like this

```
template.sendBody("direct:deleteListThenCommit", Arrays.asList("id1", "id2"));
...
from("direct:deleteListThenCommit")
    .split(body())
        .setHeader(SolrConstants.OPERATION, constant(SolrConstants.OPERATION_DELETE_BY_ID))
        .to(SOLR_ROUTE_URI)
    .end()
    .setHeader(SolrConstants.OPERATION, constant(SolrConstants.OPERATION_COMMIT))
    .to(SOLR_ROUTE_URI);
```

Answer (score 0):

A good idea when the Camel docs is not sufficient, is to look in the unit test of the Camel components in question.

See this delete test from the source code: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-solr/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/solr/SolrDeleteTest.java